# mybatis result column name when using hashmap result type issue

Tags: mybatis, ibatis

In my myBatis mapper xml file, result column name is `"COUNT(A.subj)".`
But result hashmap has `key="COUNT(A" and value=".subj)=0".`

I think "." in column name may make problems.
Is there any solution to this issue?

```
<select id="monthax_query1" parameterType="hashMap" resultType="hashMap">
SELECT **COUNT (A.subj)**
FROM
  (SELECT SUBJ
     FROM TB_A ) A
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you expect result column name to be "A".
Then considering the alias position, it applies to the sub-select, it shall then be right after the COUNT:

```
SELECT COUNT(A.subj) AS A FROM ( SELECT ...
```

Comment: I know, but I want to know other solutions of mybatis itself, not changing column alias. because there are so many SQLs to edit.